# UWPCommunityToolkit DropShadowPanel keeps Grid from stretching

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I want a grid to stretch across the screen while also having a shadow effect applied, for some reason I can't the grid to stretch when placed inside of a DropShadowPanel.

Here is an example of the desired result, but without a shadow effect:

```
<Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40"/>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Here is my xaml with a DropShadowPanel:

```
<Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <controls:DropShadowPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40">
        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this hides the second grid entirely.

Why does the grid act differently inside a DropShadowPanel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And this hides the second grid entirely.

The problem is you have not set [`HorizontalContentAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment) property of [`DropShadowPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.dropshadowpanel?view=uwp-toolkit-dotnet). I have modified your code like the following. And it works.

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel Margin="40"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          >
    <Grid Background="Red" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```